# Why trigger is doing unnecessary subtraction after a query in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have two tables:

1. Order and
2. Product.

I want a specific column(OnShelfQuantity) in the Product table to be updated as a new row is added in the Order table. I have used the below query to implement a trigger which will do that. But the problem is that when I insert a row in the Order table and then later check the Product table to see the changes, I notice that the Product table has been updated 3 times. For e.g: Order quantity inserted = 10, then only 10 should be subtracted from Product_TAB.OnShelfQuantity. But 30 gets subtracted. Please help!

```
create trigger dbo.Trigge
ON dbo.Ordertable
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
update Product_TAB set OnShelfQuantity= Product_TAB.OnShelfQuantity - Ordertable.Quantity
FROM dbo.Product_TAB
  INNER JOIN Ordertable
  ON Ordertable.ProductID = Product_TAB.ProductID;
END;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarth  Its SQL server and I am using SSMS to implement the code.

Comment: _the Product table has been updated 3 times_ ... so does Ordertable have three rows for the given ProductID? You probably want to read up on the [`inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables) used in triggers.

Comment: This trigger is probably best implemented with an indexed view

Comment: Would you like an implementation for your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that I was inserting new rows but with the same Order ID. This is why it was doing additional subtraction which I didn't require. So now I have to just insert a new row but with unique OrderID. Thanks to everyone who replied above!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use **INSERTED** table to resolve this Issue.

**Inserted table** is a table which is used by triggers to store the frequently inserted records in the tables.

So, you can use the same in your update statement to avoid this.

```
update Product_TAB set OnShelfQuantity= Product_TAB.OnShelfQuantity - 
Ordertable.Quantity
FROM dbo.Product_TAB
INNER JOIN Ordertable  ON Ordertable.ProductID = Product_TAB.ProductID
INNER JOIN inserted INS ON INS.Order_ID=Ordertable.Order_ID
```

Comment: No reason to join to the order table - everything you need from it is in the inserted table in an AFTER trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple rows in the `inserted` table.  And, these rows could have the same product.  A row in the target table is only updated *once* in an `update` statement.  Hence, you want to aggregate the data before the `update`:

```
create trigger dbo.Trigge
ON dbo.Ordertable
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN    
    update p
        set OnShelfQuantity= p.OnShelfQuantity - i.total_quantity
        from dbo.Product_TAB p JOIN
             (SELECT i.ProductId, SUM(i.Quantity) as total_quantity
              FROM inserted i
              GROUP BY i.ProductId
             ) i
             on i.ProductID = p.ProductID;
END;
```

Note that this only uses `inserted` and not the original table.